# Google Charts: information pop-ups do not work on floated div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

If you look at the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HX9YC/)

The chart on the right does not show the pop ups. 
Why is that? How can I solve it?

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'User');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Messages Sent');
    data.addRows([
        ['Amelia', 35],
        ['John', 1],
        ['Ted', 3],
        ['pat', 1]
    ]);

    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data2.addColumn('string', 'User');
    data2.addColumn('number', 'Messages Sent');
    data2.addRows([
        ['Amelia', 35],
        ['John', 1],
        ['Ted', 3],
        ['pat', 1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        'title': 'Ownership',
            'width': 250,
            'height': 250
    };

    var options2 = {
        'title': 'Ownership',
            'width': 250,
            'height': 250
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a layering issue.

If you use a DOM inspector, you will see that `chart_div_2` overlays `chart_div`.  The Visualization API cancels mouse event propagation on the container div's of a chart element, so the hover events don't get passed down to `chart_div`.

To fix this, you need to set the widths of the chart divs in CSS.  See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HX9YC/1/).